# Android laggy xml

Tags: java, android, performance

I've got problem with xml optimization ( I think ). The problem is that I want to create program to turn on and turn off the lights in my house via SMS communication. How I want it to look to have 3 rectangle shaped "frames" so I used 3 relative layouts inside relative layout (I don't know if it's correct way of doing things). And well code side like sending SMS I'm using asynctask which works fine and UI is going smooth but problem arises when turning on application, it's loading quite long even when I do not have any function on buttons and when I want to change Intent to start new activity options.xml then app crashes, when I had simple UI then intent was changing momentally, and now it's freezing. Can overloaded xml be a problem?

[My app picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKigA.png)

> ```
> <LinearLayout
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:weightSum="1"
>     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
>
>     <RelativeLayout
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:background="@drawable/border"
>         android:layout_margin="5dp"
>         android:layout_height="129dp">
>
>         <ImageView
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
>             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>             android:id="@+id/imageView" />
>     </RelativeLayout>
>
>     <RelativeLayout
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_margin="5dp"
>         android:background="@drawable/border"
>         android:layout_height="129dp">
>
>         <Button
>             android:id="@+id/onbutton"
>             android:text="WŁĄCZ"
>             android:textColor="#000000"
>             android:textSize="20sp"
>             android:layout_width="100dp"
>             android:background="@drawable/onbutton_selector"
>             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
>             android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
>             android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
>             android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
>             android:layout_height="50dp" />
>
>         <Button
>             android:text="WYŁĄCZ"
>             android:textColor="#000000"
>             android:textSize="20sp"
>             android:id="@+id/offbutton"
>
>             android:background="@drawable/offbutton_selector"
>             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
>             android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
>             android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
>             android:layout_below="@+id/nazwastacji"
>             android:layout_height="50dp"
>             android:layout_width="100dp" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:text="PODAJ NAZAWE STACJI"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:id="@+id/nazwastacji"
>             android:gravity="center"
>             android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
>             android:layout_margin="5dp"
>             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
>             android:layout_above="@+id/onbutton"
>             android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
>
>         <Button
>             android:layout_width="50dp"
>             android:layout_height="50dp"
>             android:background="@drawable/clock_selector"
>             android:id="@+id/buttonclock"
>             android:layout_below="@+id/nazwastacji"
>             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
>
>     </RelativeLayout>
>
>     <RelativeLayout
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:background="@drawable/border"
>         android:layout_margin="5dp"
>         android:layout_height="129dp">
>
>         <Button
>             android:layout_width="60dp"
>             android:id="@+id/termobutton"
>             android:background="@drawable/termometr_selector"
>             android:layout_height="60dp"
>             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
>             android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
>             android:layout_marginEnd="30dp" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:text="POMIAR TEMPERATURY"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
>             android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
>             android:id="@+id/textview1"
>             android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
>             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/termobutton"
>             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:text="°C"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textpomiar"
>             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textpomiar"
>             android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textpomiar"
>             android:id="@+id/textview2"
>             android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:text="NULL"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
>             android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
>             android:id="@+id/textpomiar"
>             android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
>             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/termobutton"
>             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textview1"
>             android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textview1" />
>     </RelativeLayout>
>
>     <RelativeLayout
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent">
>
>         <Button
>             android:background="@drawable/opcje"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:id="@+id/opcjebutton"
>             android:onClick="sendMessage"
>             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
>     </RelativeLayout>
>
> </LinearLayout> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

EDIT 
yeah i was considering lineayLayout. and i dont think there is problem with my activity, thats pretty much it. WlaczSms() is async task which works fine

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    onbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.onbutton);
    onbutton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            new WlaczSms().execute();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

And when i add to start new intent which contains oncreate method with set content view to new layout it just lags out

```
button = (Button)findViewbyId(R.id.onbutton);
button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, newclass.class);
        StartActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first tip is that you don't need two `RelativeLayout`s. A `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation=vertical` would do just fine. Secondly, if your application is taking a long time to load, it is likely that it is an issue in your `Activity`/`Fragment` files, where the actual logic is being run.

Comment: Can you show your onCreate method?

Comment: `RelativeLayout` is an 'expensive' layout, so using so many `RelativeLayouts` can cost performance.
Also, Please post your code-behind.

Comment: One layout with multiple layout isn't the best solution, this could ends up with some performance issues (that is said somewhere in the official doc). You could update that to use only one RelativeLayout I think (not checked exactly what this should look like)

Comment: Some update **1.** Why are you closing a RelativeLayout at the end ? **2.** You could remove the LinearLayout and use only one Relative. You should use a View (to confirm) to set the border and use the relative layout to defined this 129dp height of those views. But don't use a RelativeLayout just to put a Border in it. One RelativeLayout can do it.

Comment: Well im learning android for a week on my own thus i have some "clean code" issues, the way i learn, thats why i ask people here to get some advices how xml should look like ;d